# Mac Application is failed to modify a plist file after sandboxing

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I am developing a app for Mac App Store in which I need to clear recent histories of application for this I do remove a particular Key in a plist file. I do this with the help of "defaults delete" command. It works fine for me but after sandboxing my app is failed to do so.

*Let me tell you the case I am removing a key named "FXRecentFolders" from "~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist" file using "defaults delete" command. It give me the following error in sandboxing app*

**"sh: /bin/ps: Operation not permitted**

**2015-06-12 15:35:46.798 defaults[2801:101247]**

**Domain (com.apple.finder) not found.**

**Defaults have not been changed.**

**killall: warning: kill -TERM 256: Operation not permitted"**

Due to this error my project is going too late.

Comment: Yeah you cannot access that file (or pretty much any file) without explicit authority of the user.  Best way is to get the user to allow you to read and write that plist file and do it that way (via `NSOpenPanel`).  Not very elegant but there is no other choice.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Thanks Droppy I have did so first of all I have selected user's home folder with the permision of user. Then select this plist file and apply chmod 777 command on it. Then I am using defaults delete.
But its dont work for me.   :(